# IntelliJ IDEA 13 community edition - EJB Facet Missing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to generate EJB's in IDEA 13 CE for my Play Framework project, however, the options outlined in the IntelliJ documentation are missing.

For example, the docs say to go to `File->Project Structure->Modules->Click Add->Select EJB`,
however, I do not have the EJB option. All I have are Android and Groovy.

Am I missing something, or is this not supported in the CE?

Comment: I thought all of the Java EE (Enterprise Edition) stuff, including EJB support, was only available in the paid version. Do you have reason to believe that it should be available in the CE edition?

Comment: There's a complete chart of the differences between the two editions.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. It was not at all clear from the documentation I was reading via google search as to which edition was specified. Documentation here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/import-database-schema-import-mappings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJB is IntelliJ Ultimate feature

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/java_ee.html

> Support for Java EE is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html